# foreignAutoCreate field is null after update

Tags: java, android, ormlite

For a android project I'm using ORMLite version 4.45. I have a organisation model with a foreignAutoCreate field.

Organisation model:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Organisation {

    @DatabaseField (id = true)
    private UUID organisationGuid;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh=true)
    private Telnr telNr;
```

Telnr model:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Telnr {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int telnrId;

    @DatabaseField
    private String number;
```

When I add the organisation model to the database with organisationDao.createIfNotExists(organisation) everything is fine. It creates a new record in the organisation and telnr table and puts the generated telnr id in the organisation table.

Now I create a new organisation model with the same organisation UUID and perform an update

```
Organisation organisation = new Organisation();
organisation.setOrganisationGuid('same id');
organisation.setTelNr(new Telnr());
organisationDao.update(organisation);
```

I expect the record in the organisation table to be updated including the record in the Telnr table. Instead the organisation record is updated, but the telnr id in the organisation table becomes *null*. Is there a way to update the organisation and the telnr table and leave the id's intact?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do so I'll just explain what [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is doing with your code:

```
Organisation organisation = new Organisation();
organisation.setOrganisationGuid('same id');
organisation.setTelNr(new Telnr());
organisationDao.update(organisation);
```

This is updating the `Organisation` in the database that has the id `"same id"`.  I would have expected that the `telNr_id` field would be set to `0` instead of `null` since the `Telnr` object's id is most likely 0.

> I expect the record in the organisation table to be updated including the record in the Telnr table.

I don't quite understand this.  ORMLite is updating the value of `telnr_id` field to correspond to the `Telnr` object in the `Organisation`.  It doesn't do any additional changes.  ORMLite takes "Lite" seriously and tries not to do anything magic under the covers unless requested.

If you want to also update the `telNr` field then you need to do that as well:

```
organisationDao.update(organisation);
telnrDao.update(organisation.telNr);
```